# NSTimer expires when the device is locked

Tags: iphone, ios, nstimer

My application supports the GPS and it runs both in foreground and background. I have started a timer , which is working perfectly unless the device is locked. 
I want the timer to keep on running even when the device is locked.

Can anyone tell me how this can be done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whichever way you start a timer, the default run mode is like below:

```
     Timer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(run) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

     [[ NSRunLoop currentRunLoop ] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode ];
```

using `NSDefaultRunLoopMode`. You want more flexibility, so change forMode to take `NSRunLoopCommonModes` instead and you should be fine.

Comment: So if we use the NSRunLoop , the timer will run irrespective of the status of the iPhone. Am i right ?

Comment: The NSRunLoop is always used, it is the backbone of the main application thread. NSTimers are scheduled on it. They are scheduled with run modes, which determine if they can be interrupted or not. default is not very good, it gets interrupted by things like scrollviews. It has been a while since I have tested, but common modes rarely if ever gets interrupted. I am certain it will work for what you need it for. Apple doesn't provide a very good description of what interrupts these modes

Comment: Thanks for the description :) Hope the timer will keep on running in my application except when the device is switched off.

Comment: Has this been proven in ios 5? As far as I know this no longer works.